# Nunit : How can I retry fixture if one test fails?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nunit

I noticed that sometimes my tests from one test fixture randomly fail on Teamcity, but I can't reproduce this crashes in my pc
I use  **[Retry(RetryNumber)]** attribute, but it helps only sometimes
Is there any way to set retry **for Fixture and repeat whole fixture if one test fails?**
Using ***C#+Nunit+Selenium webdriver***

Comment: No, RetryAttribute is limited to methods.

Comment: Good tests are deterministic/predictable; and they also shouldn't depend on each other. Tests that fail randomly will cause you a lot of pain (particularly if you also have Continuous Integration, which I'm guessing is what you're using TeamCity for). If you can't tell why they are failing, change the Asserts to give you extra information, or (if using NUnit3) use "TestContext.WriteLine" to produce information that may help you diagnose the problem. If you post the test people may be able to suggest what your problem is.

Comment: I understand that it is not good when tests are failing randomly without any reason for that.

Comment: And according to issue I described in first post - now it works correct in TC, without any code changes 
Don't know what it was